# Is there a way to make Software Updater use apt-fast as a backend?

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-updater, apt-fast

I've been using apt-fast in the command line for some time now and have enjoyed how it speeds upgrades by downloading packages in parallel.

It would be great if Software Updater could also gain the update/upgrade download speed boost from apt-fast.

Software Updater seems merely to be a gui for the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, is there a way to switch out apt-get for apt-fast?

Comment: Will this ever be rolled out officially?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible. You have to write an apt-fast backend (in Python) for the Software Updater (`update-manager` package). Take a look at the [Synaptic backend](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/update-manager/main/view/head:/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendSynaptic.py). This backend also calls an executable (synaptic). Perhaps just change the command line options a bit and you are done.

Install it to `/usr/lib/pythonX/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/YourBackend.py` and load it in `.../backend/__init__.py` file ("get_backend" method).

Comment: Doesn't update-manager already have a backend which could be edited? /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend__init__.py?

Comment: That's the initialization method for the backends (with "get_backend" method to select backend).

Comment: Over my head I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

This init and destructor I get from Pascal (objective P), I'm not that dated but I use FPC... but a touch confused as the python implementation of it.

You are saying that py calls a caller to call the package mananger? Just invoke it directly with a shell os.system call...sometimes I wonder who writes these things...

```
can=object
    coffee=record;
        liquid:array[1..x] of caffeine;
        caffeine:variable;
        sugar:constant;
        creamer:variable;
   end;
nextCan:^can;
prevCan:^can;
init()
drink.can()
throw.can()
destroy()
end;
```

or something like that.